# iTextSharp set dynamic margins

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need help with an issue I've been experiencing with iTextSharp.
I want to set the margins dynamically depending on wether the page has a header/footer or not, without having to always set it up manually for each page. As it does that, though it always seems to do it on the page after the one I want. I reckon it must be a question of putting my code before something. I'm thinking that when the OnStartPage method gets called the NewPage method of the Document class has already been called. Is that it? That's the only plausible explaination that makes sense to me.

I could do this on the class that creates the pdf file. Call the method everytime before calling the NewPage method. But I want something more automated.

So, here are the methods that will create the actual pdf file:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class ITextEvents : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        Font FontRegular = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12);
        // This is the contentbyte object of the writer
        PdfContentByte cb;

        // we will put the final number of pages in a template
        PdfTemplate headerTemplate, footerTemplate;

        // this is the BaseFont we are going to use for the header / footer
        BaseFont bf = null;

        List<int> PagesWithNoFooter, PagesWithNoHeader;

        float LeftMargin, RightMargin, TopMarginWithHeader, TopMarginWithNoHeader, BottomMarginWithFooter, BottomMarginWithNoFooter;

        /// <summary>
        /// The constructor for getting some presets
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pagesWithNoHeader">List of pages in which the user doesn't want a header.</param>
        /// <param name="pagesWithNoFooter">List of pages in which the user doesn't want a footer.</param>
        /// <param name="leftMargin">The page's default left margin.</param>
        /// <param name="rightMargin">The page's default right margin.</param>
        /// <param name="topMarginWithNoHeader">The page's top margin for a page with no header.</param>
        /// <param name="topMarginWithHeader">The page's top margin for a page with header.</param>
        /// <param name="bottomMarginWithNoFooter">The page's bottom margin for a page with no footer.</param>
        /// <param name="bottomMarginWithFooter">The page's bottom margin for a page with footer.</param>
        public ITextEvents(List<int> pagesWithNoHeader, List<int> pagesWithNoFooter, float leftMargin, float rightMargin, float topMarginWithNoHeader, float topMarginWithHeader, float bottomMarginWithNoFooter, float bottomMarginWithFooter)
        {
            PagesWithNoFooter = pagesWithNoFooter.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
            PagesWithNoHeader = pagesWithNoHeader.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
            LeftMargin = leftMargin;
            RightMargin = rightMargin;
            TopMarginWithHeader = topMarginWithHeader;
            TopMarginWithNoHeader = topMarginWithNoHeader;
            BottomMarginWithFooter = bottomMarginWithFooter;
            BottomMarginWithNoFooter = bottomMarginWithNoFooter;
        }

        public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            try
            {
                bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                cb = writer.DirectContent;
                headerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(100, 100);
                footerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                //handle exception here
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioe)
            {
                //handle exception here
            }
        }

        public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
            float[] docMargins = SetDocumentMargins(writer.CurrentPageNumber);
            document.SetMargins(docMargins[0], docMargins[1], docMargins[2], docMargins[3]);
        }

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
            // Adds the footer if the user didn't specify the page number 
            if (!PagesWithNoFooter.Contains(document.PageNumber))
            {
                //Add paging to footer
                {
                    string paging = "Página " + writer.PageNumber + " de ";
                    float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(paging, 12);
                    float posX = (document.PageSize.Width / 2) - (len / 2);
                    cb.BeginText();
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(posX, document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
                    cb.ShowText(paging);
                    cb.EndText();
                    cb.AddTemplate(footerTemplate, posX + len, document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
                }
            }
            // Adds the header if the user didn't specify the page number
            if (!PagesWithNoHeader.Contains(document.PageNumber))
            {
                Phrase p1Header = new Phrase("Sample Header Here", FontRegular);

                //Create PdfTable object
                PdfPTable pdfTab = new PdfPTable(3);

                //We will have to create separate cells to include image logo and 2 separate strings
                //Row 1
                PdfPCell pdfCell1 = new PdfPCell();
                PdfPCell pdfCell2 = new PdfPCell(p1Header);
                PdfPCell pdfCell3 = new PdfPCell();
                String text = "Page " + writer.PageNumber + " of ";

                //Row 2
                PdfPCell pdfCell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sub Header Description", FontRegular));
                //Row 3


                PdfPCell pdfCell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date:", FontRegular));
                PdfPCell pdfCell6 = new PdfPCell();
                PdfPCell pdfCell7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TIME:" + string.Format("{0:t}", DateTime.Now), FontRegular));


                //set the alignment of all three cells and set border to 0
                pdfCell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell4.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell5.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell6.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell7.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;


                pdfCell2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
                pdfCell3.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                pdfCell4.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
                pdfCell5.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                pdfCell6.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                pdfCell7.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;


                pdfCell4.Colspan = 3;



                pdfCell1.Border = 0;
                pdfCell2.Border = 0;
                pdfCell3.Border = 0;
                pdfCell4.Border = 0;
                pdfCell5.Border = 0;
                pdfCell6.Border = 0;
                pdfCell7.Border = 0;


                //add all three cells into PdfTable
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell1);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell2);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell3);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell4);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell5);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell6);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell7);

                pdfTab.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 80f;
                pdfTab.WidthPercentage = 70;



                //call WriteSelectedRows of PdfTable. This writes rows from PdfWriter in PdfTable
                //first param is start row. -1 indicates there is no end row and all the rows to be included to write
                //Third and fourth param is x and y position to start writing
                pdfTab.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 40, document.PageSize.Height - 30, writer.DirectContent);

                //Move the pointer and draw line to separate header section from rest of page
                cb.MoveTo(40, document.PageSize.Height - 100);
                cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width - 40, document.PageSize.Height - 100);
                cb.Stroke();

            }
        }

        public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

            footerTemplate.BeginText();
            footerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
            footerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
            footerTemplate.ShowText(writer.PageNumber.ToString());
            footerTemplate.EndText();
        }

        private float[] SetDocumentMargins(int pageNumber)
        {
            float topMargin = 0, bottomMargin = 0;

            // Sets the bottom margin depending on wether the page has a footer
            if (PagesWithNoFooter.Contains(pageNumber))
                bottomMargin = BottomMarginWithNoFooter;
            else
                bottomMargin = BottomMarginWithFooter;

            // Sets the top margin depending on wether the page has a header
            if (PagesWithNoHeader.Contains(pageNumber))
                topMargin = TopMarginWithNoHeader;
            else
                topMargin = TopMarginWithHeader;

            return new float[] { LeftMargin, RightMargin, topMargin, bottomMargin };
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the PdfPageEventHelper:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class ITextEvents : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        Font FontRegular = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12);
        // This is the contentbyte object of the writer
        PdfContentByte cb;

        // we will put the final number of pages in a template
        PdfTemplate headerTemplate, footerTemplate;

        // this is the BaseFont we are going to use for the header / footer
        BaseFont bf = null;

        List<int> PagesWithNoFooter, PagesWithNoHeader;

        float LeftMargin, RightMargin, TopMarginWithHeader, TopMarginWithNoHeader, BottomMarginWithFooter, BottomMarginWithNoFooter;

        /// <summary>
        /// The constructor for getting some presets
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pagesWithNoHeader">List of pages in which the user doesn't want a header.</param>
        /// <param name="pagesWithNoFooter">List of pages in which the user doesn't want a footer.</param>
        /// <param name="leftMargin">The page's default left margin.</param>
        /// <param name="rightMargin">The page's default right margin.</param>
        /// <param name="topMarginWithNoHeader">The page's top margin for a page with no header.</param>
        /// <param name="topMarginWithHeader">The page's top margin for a page with header.</param>
        /// <param name="bottomMarginWithNoFooter">The page's bottom margin for a page with no footer.</param>
        /// <param name="bottomMarginWithFooter">The page's bottom margin for a page with footer.</param>
        public ITextEvents(List<int> pagesWithNoHeader, List<int> pagesWithNoFooter, float leftMargin, float rightMargin, float topMarginWithNoHeader, float topMarginWithHeader, float bottomMarginWithNoFooter, float bottomMarginWithFooter)
        {
            PagesWithNoFooter = pagesWithNoFooter.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
            PagesWithNoHeader = pagesWithNoHeader.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
            LeftMargin = leftMargin;
            RightMargin = rightMargin;
            TopMarginWithHeader = topMarginWithHeader;
            TopMarginWithNoHeader = topMarginWithNoHeader;
            BottomMarginWithFooter = bottomMarginWithFooter;
            BottomMarginWithNoFooter = bottomMarginWithNoFooter;
        }

        public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            try
            {
                bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                cb = writer.DirectContent;
                headerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(100, 100);
                footerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                //handle exception here
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioe)
            {
                //handle exception here
            }
        }

        public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
            float[] docMargins = SetDocumentMargins(writer.CurrentPageNumber);
            document.SetMargins(docMargins[0], docMargins[1], docMargins[2], docMargins[3]);
        }

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
            // Adds the footer if the user didn't specify the page number 
            if (!PagesWithNoFooter.Contains(document.PageNumber))
            {
                //Add paging to footer
                {
                    string paging = "Página " + writer.PageNumber + " de ";
                    float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(paging, 12);
                    float posX = (document.PageSize.Width / 2) - (len / 2);
                    cb.BeginText();
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(posX, document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
                    cb.ShowText(paging);
                    cb.EndText();
                    cb.AddTemplate(footerTemplate, posX + len, document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
                }
            }
            // Adds the header if the user didn't specify the page number
            if (!PagesWithNoHeader.Contains(document.PageNumber))
            {
                Phrase p1Header = new Phrase("Sample Header Here", FontRegular);

                //Create PdfTable object
                PdfPTable pdfTab = new PdfPTable(3);

                //We will have to create separate cells to include image logo and 2 separate strings
                //Row 1
                PdfPCell pdfCell1 = new PdfPCell();
                PdfPCell pdfCell2 = new PdfPCell(p1Header);
                PdfPCell pdfCell3 = new PdfPCell();
                String text = "Page " + writer.PageNumber + " of ";

                //Row 2
                PdfPCell pdfCell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sub Header Description", FontRegular));
                //Row 3


                PdfPCell pdfCell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date:", FontRegular));
                PdfPCell pdfCell6 = new PdfPCell();
                PdfPCell pdfCell7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TIME:" + string.Format("{0:t}", DateTime.Now), FontRegular));


                //set the alignment of all three cells and set border to 0
                pdfCell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell4.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell5.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell6.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfCell7.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;


                pdfCell2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
                pdfCell3.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                pdfCell4.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
                pdfCell5.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                pdfCell6.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                pdfCell7.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;


                pdfCell4.Colspan = 3;



                pdfCell1.Border = 0;
                pdfCell2.Border = 0;
                pdfCell3.Border = 0;
                pdfCell4.Border = 0;
                pdfCell5.Border = 0;
                pdfCell6.Border = 0;
                pdfCell7.Border = 0;


                //add all three cells into PdfTable
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell1);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell2);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell3);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell4);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell5);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell6);
                pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell7);

                pdfTab.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 80f;
                pdfTab.WidthPercentage = 70;



                //call WriteSelectedRows of PdfTable. This writes rows from PdfWriter in PdfTable
                //first param is start row. -1 indicates there is no end row and all the rows to be included to write
                //Third and fourth param is x and y position to start writing
                pdfTab.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 40, document.PageSize.Height - 30, writer.DirectContent);

                //Move the pointer and draw line to separate header section from rest of page
                cb.MoveTo(40, document.PageSize.Height - 100);
                cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width - 40, document.PageSize.Height - 100);
                cb.Stroke();

            }
        }

        public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

            footerTemplate.BeginText();
            footerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
            footerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
            footerTemplate.ShowText(writer.PageNumber.ToString());
            footerTemplate.EndText();
        }

        private float[] SetDocumentMargins(int pageNumber)
        {
            float topMargin = 0, bottomMargin = 0;

            // Sets the bottom margin depending on wether the page has a footer
            if (PagesWithNoFooter.Contains(pageNumber))
                bottomMargin = BottomMarginWithNoFooter;
            else
                bottomMargin = BottomMarginWithFooter;

            // Sets the top margin depending on wether the page has a header
            if (PagesWithNoHeader.Contains(pageNumber))
                topMargin = TopMarginWithNoHeader;
            else
                topMargin = TopMarginWithHeader;

            return new float[] { LeftMargin, RightMargin, topMargin, bottomMargin };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I'm thinking that when the OnStartPage method gets called the NewPage method of the Document class has already been called. Is that it?"* - Yes, that's the case.

Comment: That's what I thought. Is there any event that gets called before?

Comment: If not, well, I'll just have to do it everytime I create a new page.

Comment: Why are you using the old iText version in your project? Isn't it easier to use iText 7, and to define a custom renderer? Layout functionality has significantly improved in iText 7: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, for some reason I thought I had installed version 7. But you're right. Thanks. Also, I see there's a lot of documentation, though I don't see any examples. Is there anywhere I can see some implementation examples?

Comment: Nevermind. Found them.  I'll check out the examples of that version. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, I've been tinkering with v7 and it's really improved. I find it much easier to work with. :) I have a question, though. Is it possible the get the Document object (not the PdfDocument object) in the Event object of the HandleEvent function? I'd like to get to it somehow to be able to set the document's margins.

Comment: There actually might be numerous `Document` objects. Or none at all. Thus, there is no generic way to attach *the* `Document` to an event. But you as the architect of your specific program obviously can add a `Document` property to your event listener which you set to your `Document` instance as early as possible, e.g. right after instantiating the `Document` and the event listener.

Comment: @mkl thanks. I thought about that. Though I wasn't really sure about if it would reference the main document (aka the updated document, with the added pages) or just keep the value that was passed forever. I was going to give it a try as a last resort (I'm working in an extension for Outsystems, so I can't really debug c# code, which is a bit frustrating). But anyway, I'm happy it worked. So far so good. :)